# Magento 2.3 add chunk of javascript code to my Custom Theme (phtml file)

Tags: javascript, theme, magento2.3

I need to implement a Few Functions of **javascript** and a **jquery** code in to a phtml file in my Custom Theme.
I have read about the different way of implementation but I am not sure which is the best way for my 3 little functions. The chunk of code is using jquery.

Putting the js code directly to the phtml file works but I guess it is not the recommended way.
how i can call a one **phtml** file for whole website **jquery** and **javascript** code.

Can anyone guide me? Thanks!

Comment: have you read the docs?

Comment: Yes but I am a bit confused after and I am not sure what is the best way for my example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First You Need to  create a **javascript** file under this file path locations :-

> app/design/frontend/Vendorname/Themename/web/js/All.js

Put your functions or jquery code in this file.

And then Call this **js** File in your theme like this.

File Path :-

> app/design/frontend/Vendorname/ThemenameMagento_Theme/layout/default_head_blocks.xml
>   code of call All.js file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
* Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
* See COPYING.txt for license details.
*/
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
    <script src="js/All.js" />
    </head>
</page>
```

Or before.body.end

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
* Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
* See COPYING.txt for license details.
*/
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="before.body.end">
            <script src="js/activeRobotsAll.js" />
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Call **phtml** file. you need to create a phtml file in this file path location :-

> app/design/frontend/Vendorname/Themename/Magento_Theme/templates/test.phtml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
* Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
* See COPYING.txt for license details.
*/
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="before.body.end">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="test_file" template="Magento_Theme::test.phtml"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

**test.phtml** file

```
<?php  
        <script type="text/javascript">
           //enter you javascript code,functions here...
        </script>

     ?>
```

Hope this helpful.

Comment: Thanks. How would the code look if I want to put the file before.body.ends instead of the head section?

Comment: Check my code before.body.end

Comment: Shouldn't I use the <script type="text/x-magento-init"> in my phtml file?

Comment: Yes, you can add javascript code in your phtml file.

Comment: Can you tell me exactly how to do that in the Magento Way?

Comment: Check my code add phtml file.

Comment: ok thanks but how would this phtml file look?

Comment: Check my phtml file code

Comment: it's helpful please accept my answer.